# Angular+2: how to build two differents bundles in the same index.html?

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there a way to build another typescript file to be injected in index html and load async at the same time that the angular bundle?
So, in this way we could have index.html with polifills, angular app, and our other typescript bundle compiled loaded async

Comment: it sounds like you might be interested in lazy loading some of your app (instead of loading the entire thing at once). https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Comment: lazyloading ngmodules is for modules from angular, i want to load async another script(js file) that has javascript and nothings of angular, but that file is in typescript, so i have to compile, and then this has to be injected in the same html as async i thinks, but in a angular project i dont know how to configure angularjson or tsconfig to do this.